# Can't use a Jar file in Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

I'm trying to use an external jar file in my Android project, I follwed this step for including it:

- I put the jar file in libs.
- I configured the build path and now I can see the jar file in the Referenced Libraries section of the project.
- I use the import to bring the class that I need inside the program.

But I always get NoClassDefFoundError. This jar already works with a classic java program.

Comment: Do you see the jar listed in the Android Dependencies folder?

Comment: Hmmm, looks like you're doing it right. Perhaps you have another class with the same name in your project. E.g. android.SomeClass vs java.SomeClass which is causing the conflict??

Comment: For what it's worth, I've used external jars *without* doing the "add to build path".  Have you tried that? You can also check the Project Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and see if it's listed (or add it) there.

Comment: I see the jar listed in the Android Dependencies folder, and I've not another class with the same name in the project. If I'm not getting wrong if I remove the library from the build path I get an error directly from the compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution found was recompile the library with the version 6 of java and using the jar fail obtained

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the jar is being built with the app. In eclipse,

`right click on project --> build path --> configure build path.`

Make sure the library is checked in the Order and Export tab.

Comment: Forgot to say that, I've already checked, I even tried to put it at the bottom of the list "Order and Export", but nothing.

Comment: what about the top? It's worth a shot.

Comment: Do you mean at the top of Order and Export tab? If so I've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android SDK 17 there is not even necessary to manually add the jar files to buildpath, because they are added automatically, as stated [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects). Then I would suggest to:

- remove the library from buildpath
- clean the project
- make sure the jar file is located in a folder called `libs` (not `lib`) located in the root folder of your project
- refresh the project
- run the project

Comment: Thank you.  I solved the problem, it was only that the jar i was using it was compiled with java 7, i recompiled the jar with java 1.6 and it works!

Comment: @user2220739 If you've solved your own problem then please post the solution here as an answer and mark it as accepted so that others may benefit from the knowledge.